# Tortoise SVN gives error when committing a large file

Tags: tortoisesvn, dreamhost

I have a couple of large files I'm trying to commit...
512MB, 668MB, 724MB, 928MB, 948MB, 1.97GB, 2.70GB

These are the errors I'm getting

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):

Error: PUT of

Error: '/svn-documents/!svn/wrk/6f3dec2d-61b9-c64d-b390-4a7f8bec50db/path/Class.one':

Error: Could not send request body: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the

Error: remote host.

Error:  (my site)
```

To get this error, I right click on the file, then click SVN Commit. I then press okay at the next window. It starts to transfer the file and then gives me the error.

Is there a way around this? Maybe another way I can put the file there, even manually?

EDIT: based on some research, this may be a Dreamhost issue not allowing commits of greater than .5GB... so some sort of workaround would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) on the server can also help in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to SVN but there might be limits on hard drive space, operating system limitation to temporary directory at both sender and receiver ends. Also there is a possibility of timeout by your router or internet connection.

Is this error immidiate or does it come after a fixed amount of delay. Try uploading the smallest file first and if not try a file of about 20 MB. Hit and Trial might solve the mystery which may easily be resolved from log files on repository.

[Read this about Subversion Best Practices](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html)

Comment: It happens after a delay... it sends part of the file and then I get the error. I was able to commit a 300MB file so approx that seems to be the limit.